# How to create/extract the EDID for/from a Monitor

Tags: 11.10, monitor, hdmi, vga

Is it possible to create or extract the Extended Display Identification Data (EDID) for/from a monitor. I have some issues with my monitor with the VGA and HDMI cables and I would like to test if by adding the EDID to the Nvidia Settings it could help in solve this issues.

With the VGA cable I get a black out error and with the HDMI I get some EDID errors (bad EDID). So how can I create the EDID or extract it from the monitor by detecting its capabilities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it. Was wrongly searching in the apt search box for ESID instead of EDID. Found the `read-edid` app which comes with 2 programs, `get-edid` which is the one I need to extract the data from the Monitor and then `parse-edid` which reads the binary output from `get-edid` (In the same pipeline) and parses it in a human readable format. After this I can include it in the Nvidia Settings and test out the outcome but at least I can extract the EDID from the Monitor.

The how to use it is also here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/get-edid.1.html

but basically is what I just did:

`get-edid > filename`  then `parse-edid < filename` or just do `get-edid | parse-edid`

Also the nvidia-settings includes a "Adquire EDID" button that saves into binary or text format.

I will leave this here although this question might not come out a lot, it will help anybody that is looking for something related to extracting the EDID.

Comment: `parse-edid` had problems reading the dump that `nvidia-settings` creates. `edid-decode` worked though.

Comment: Thank you @DanMan this is very important.