# GDM and GNOME at wrong resolution

Tags: gnome, 17.10, display-resolution, gdm, wayland

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu 17.10 and having all sorts of issues with screen resolution. The login screen sets the resolution to 1920x2160 (have no idea where it is getting this from) which is unreadable and after I log in the display just says "no signal". If I login with Xorg instead of Wayland (I think this is what I'm doing but can't read the screen to be sure) I get a usable 1920x1080 resolution.

For the first issue I've tried adding the following to the init script (`/etc/gdm3/Init/Default`) near the end:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_user"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 "1920x1080_user"
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --primary --mode "1920x1080_user"
```

This seems to have no effect, but works fine when I run it manually (logged in with Xorg).

The output from `xrandr -q` looks like this:

```
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
    3840x2160     30.00 +  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
    1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98
    1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
    1680x1050     59.88
```

It sounds very similar to this unanswered issue: [Ubuntu 17.10 GDM Login Screen Resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977901/ubuntu-17-10-gdm-login-screen-resolution)

My display is a TV via HDMI and a graphics card is an AMD RX480.

For the second issue I have no idea where to start.

Results of `lshw output`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Results of `modinfo amdgpu`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    AMD GPU
author:         AMD linux driver team
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_gpu_info.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_gpu_info.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_mec2.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_sdma1.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_sdma1.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_sdma1.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_sdma1.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_sdma1.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/si58_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/banks_k_2_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_k_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_mc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_mc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_mc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_mc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_mc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_asd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_sos.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_rlc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_mec2.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_mec.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_me.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_pfp.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_ce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_sdma1.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_sdma.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_uvd.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/vega10_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/stoney_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/carrizo_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_vce.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/raven_vcn.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris12_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_k_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_smc_sk.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris11_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_k_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_smc_sk.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/polaris10_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/fiji_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_k_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/tonga_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_k_smc.bin
firmware:       amdgpu/topaz_smc.bin
srcversion:     CCBC1452CE0D66FAED2A9B1
alias:          pci:v00001002d000015DDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000687Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000686Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006868sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006867sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006864sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006863sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006862sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006861sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006860sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000699Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006997sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006995sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006987sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006986sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006985sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006981sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006980sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067CFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067CAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067D0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067FFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067EFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067E0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000098E4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009877sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009876sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009875sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009874sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009870sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000730Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00007300sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006939sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006938sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006930sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000692Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000692Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006929sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006928sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006921sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006920sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006907sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006903sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006902sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006901sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006900sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000985Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009859sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009858sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009857sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009856sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009855sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009854sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009853sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009852sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009851sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009850sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000983Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009839sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009838sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009837sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009836sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009835sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009834sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009833sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009832sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009831sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009830sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067BEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067BAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067B9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067B8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067B1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067B0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067AAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067A9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067A8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067A2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d000067A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000665Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000665Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000665Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006658sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006651sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006650sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006649sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006647sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006646sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006641sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006640sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000131Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000131Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000131Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001317sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001316sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001313sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001310sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000130Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001309sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001305sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00001304sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000666Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006667sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006665sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006664sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006663sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006660sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000683Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000683Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000683Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006839sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006838sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006837sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006835sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006831sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006830sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000682Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000682Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000682Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000682Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000682Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006829sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006828sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006827sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006826sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006825sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006824sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006823sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006822sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006821sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006820sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006631sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006623sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006621sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006620sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006617sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006613sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006611sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006610sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006607sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006606sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006605sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006604sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006603sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006602sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006601sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006600sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006819sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006818sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006817sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006816sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006811sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006810sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006809sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006808sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006806sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006802sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006801sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006800sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000679Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000679Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000679Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000679Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006799sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006798sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006792sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006791sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006790sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000678Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006788sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006784sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00006780sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        drm,drm_kms_helper,ttm,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
name:           amdgpu
vermagic:       4.13.0-16-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:

sig_key:

sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           vramlimit:Restrict VRAM for testing, in megabytes (int)
parm:           gartsize:Size of PCIE/IGP gart to setup in megabytes (32, 64, etc., -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           moverate:Maximum buffer migration rate in MB/s. (32, 64, etc., -1=auto, 0=1=disabled) (int)
parm:           benchmark:Run benchmark (int)
parm:           test:Run tests (int)
parm:           audio:Audio enable (-1 = auto, 0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           disp_priority:Display Priority (0 = auto, 1 = normal, 2 = high) (int)
parm:           hw_i2c:hw i2c engine enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           pcie_gen2:PCIE Gen2 mode (-1 = auto, 0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           msi:MSI support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           lockup_timeout:GPU lockup timeout in ms (default 0 = disable) (int)
parm:           dpm:DPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           fw_load_type:firmware loading type (0 = direct, 1 = SMU, 2 = PSP, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           aspm:ASPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           runpm:PX runtime pm (1 = force enable, 0 = disable, -1 = PX only default) (int)
parm:           ip_block_mask:IP Block Mask (all blocks enabled (default)) (uint)
parm:           bapm:BAPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           deep_color:Deep Color support (1 = enable, 0 = disable (default)) (int)
parm:           vm_size:VM address space size in gigabytes (default 64GB) (int)
parm:           vm_block_size:VM page table size in bits (default depending on vm_size) (int)
parm:           vm_fault_stop:Stop on VM fault (0 = never (default), 1 = print first, 2 = always) (int)
parm:           vm_debug:Debug VM handling (0 = disabled (default), 1 = enabled) (int)
parm:           vm_update_mode:VM update using CPU (0 = never (default except for large BAR(LB)), 1 = Graphics only, 2 = Compute only (default for LB), 3 = Both (int)
parm:           vram_page_split:Number of pages after we split VRAM allocations (default 1024, -1 = disable) (int)
parm:           exp_hw_support:experimental hw support (1 = enable, 0 = disable (default)) (int)
parm:           sched_jobs:the max number of jobs supported in the sw queue (default 32) (int)
parm:           sched_hw_submission:the max number of HW submissions (default 2) (int)
parm:           ppfeaturemask:all power features enabled (default)) (int)
parm:           no_evict:Support pinning request from user space (1 = enable, 0 = disable (default)) (int)
parm:           direct_gma_size:Direct GMA size in megabytes (max 96MB) (int)
parm:           pcie_gen_cap:PCIE Gen Caps (0: autodetect (default)) (uint)
parm:           pcie_lane_cap:PCIE Lane Caps (0: autodetect (default)) (uint)
parm:           cg_mask:Clockgating flags mask (0 = disable clock gating) (uint)
parm:           pg_mask:Powergating flags mask (0 = disable power gating) (uint)
parm:           disable_cu:Disable CUs (se.sh.cu,...) (charp)
parm:           virtual_display:Enable virtual display feature (the virtual_display will be set like xxxx:xx:xx.x,x;xxxx:xx:xx.x,x) (charp)
parm:           ngg:Next Generation Graphics (1 = enable, 0 = disable(default depending on gfx)) (int)
parm:           prim_buf_per_se:the size of Primitive Buffer per Shader Engine (default depending on gfx) (int)
parm:           pos_buf_per_se:the size of Position Buffer per Shader Engine (default depending on gfx) (int)
parm:           cntl_sb_buf_per_se:the size of Control Sideband per Shader Engine (default depending on gfx) (int)
parm:           param_buf_per_se:the size of Off-Chip Pramater Cache per Shader Engine (default depending on gfx) (int)
parm:           job_hang_limit:how much time allow a job hang and not drop it (default 0) (int)
parm:           lbpw:Load Balancing Per Watt (LBPW) support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           si_support:SI support (1 = enabled, 0 = disabled (default)) (int)
parm:           cik_support:CIK support (1 = enabled, 0 = disabled (default)) (int)
```

*Edit* - It looks like the init script is not being run at all. I tried writing to a file and there is no output. Are there any logs anywhere? The permissions on `/var/log/gdm3` seemed a bit screwed up as well.

Comment: Please provide current [video driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/23240/349837).

Comment: what brand/model of TV?  might be a weird EDID situation.  see eg https://askubuntu.com/q/81370/669043 https://askubuntu.com/q/483649/669043